# Apply styling on variable inside template literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

`make ${text} bold`

I am trying to apply styling to TEXT which is inside backtick operator.

Comment: HTML ? `make <b>${text}</b> bold`?

Answer (score 0):

Insert style in backtick

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content')
var text = 'text'
content.innerHTML = `make <b>${text}</b> bold`
```

```html
<div id='content'> </div>
```